# mocked class function should be called once but call_count == 0?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following `mod1.py` to be tested.

```
_p = None

def get_p():
    global _p
    if _p is None:
        _p = P()
    return _p

def deco(f):
    p = get_p()
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        p.func1()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And `P`,

```
class P:
    def func1(self):
        pass
```

And I have the following test code.

```
@mock.patch('mod1.get_p')
def test_1(mocked):
    mocked.get_p = mock.Mock(P) 

    @mod1.deco()
    def test():
        pass

    test() # will call _p.func1() once

    assert mocked.func1.call_count == 1 # func1.count_count is zero
```

However, it failed with

```
>       assert p.func1.call_count == 1
E       AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
```

Why the call_count is 0?

Comment: this code is a bit confusing to understand what the issue is and not sure why you are doing `mocked.get_p = Mock` when it is already mocked with the decorator

Comment: sorry the indent was messed up.

Comment: I updated my answer, try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why code does not work**

Generally, you get 0 calls, because your decorator does not call `_p.func1`.

You don't have to write `mocked.get_p` since you already fake it, hence your `mocked` param represents `mod.get_p` function.

Also you should not redefine `mocked` variable as it is already instance of `mock.Mock`

In `mod1` you have an error, your `deco` decorator is wrong, I recommend you to read more about python decorators.

**Working code for your case**

`mod1.py`

```py
class P:
    def func1(self):
        pass


_p = None

def get_p():
    global _p
    if _p is None:
        _p = P()
    return _p

 # other code omitted, it's a decorator which will call _p.func1 once
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        p = get_p()
        p.func1()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

`test_mod1.py`

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import mod1

class TestFunc1(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mod1.get_p')
    def test_1(self, mocked):
        _p_mock = mock.Mock()
        mocked.return_value = _p_mock

        @mod1.deco
        def test():
            pass

        test()

        _p_mock.func1.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Run on openSUSE Tumbleweed, Python3.8.5:

```
> python test_mod1.py

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: It seems the line should be `mocked.return_value = _p_mock.return_value`. However, it still failed with the same reason.

Comment: Please, could you show more code? I am sure that reason is not in test. Also the line you said to be changed is ok and should works.